# Creating a customized scale bar in QGIS

Tags: qgis, scale-bar

I want to create a scale bar in QGIS that also includes the scale written out as text - like 1:20 000 or 1:10 000.

I would like it to appear just under the scale bar itself.
Can this be done automatically in any way or shall I just use a ordinary textbox?

If I get it to work automatically, the risk of me changing the scale in one place and not the other will not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The easiest way to do this is to add two scale bars, one as a bar and the other with the numeric style set. As long as you select the same map for the two scale bars you will never need to worry about sync'ing them.